# /path/:id not switching view when Link is to={"/path/" + slug}

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-hooks, slug

I am trying to get a specific post appear by using its slug. I have sucessfully made this happen by setting the Route path to /journal:id and Link to={"/journal" + post.field.slug}. However this is not what I want the url to look like. Any guess why the Route won't recognize the added slash?

```
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/journal' component={Journal} />
                <Route path='/journal/:id' component={SinglePost} />
                <Route path='/shop' component={Shop} />
                <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
            </Switch>
```

When I click on the Link inside of Journal that should display the SinglePost component, the URL changes but the view doesn't change and I still see the Journal. This is the Link:

```
        <Link
            className='posts__post'
            key={post.fields.slug}
            to={"/journal/" + post.fields.slug}
        >
```

Comment: what is not working? can you post a result that is not working

Comment: @Hakier went ahead and solved it. The problem was that the path='/journal' was overriding my path='/journal/:id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple paths that have common parts like `/journal` and `/journal/:id` (common part is `/journal`) you should add attribute `exact` to shorter path to not stop searching for a route if only partially matched

```
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/journal' component={Journal} />
        <Route path='/journal/:id' component={SinglePost} />
        <Route path='/shop' component={Shop} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
    </Switch>
```